# Distributed Cache - Arbitration Port 22235 - When it will be listening?

Tags: sharepoint-server, distributedcache

There is a question that is bothering me for a while now: why the Distributed Cache service TCP port 22235 is NOT LISTENING?

[image]

I have two Distributed Cache nodes, Windows firewall has been turned off on both nodes. I tried many scenarios, but the Arbitration port 22235 still not listening.

both nodes are configured the same:

[image]

Thanks in Advance, [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h35kj.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXhku.png [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6jS.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgHFG.png

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it *must* listen on 22235?
This **port is used only if a cache host fails**, to make certain that the cache host is unavailable.
The process does not have to occupy the port all the time if it is not needed.
It shouldn't bother you as long as everything works.

---

Off-topic:
It is not necessary to use *portqry* to check open ports.
If you want to know if a process on local computer is listening on a certain port, you can use built-in tools:

- cmd: `netstat -ano | findstr :22235`
- powershell: `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 22234`
- GUI: **Resource monitor** (resmon.exe) - *Network* - *TCP Connections*.

If you want to know if a process on a remote PC is available on a certain port, you can also use powershell: `tnc 10.200.199.244 -Port 22235`

Comment: I am trying to understand more about the ports used by the distributed cache, all the literature says that 22235 is used when a cache host fails. however, despite all the tests I've done with multiple cache hosts, I never saw it in action. if it is not supposed to be listening, what it is then the purpose?

Comment: By the way, I've done all the tests with netstat, Get-NetTCPCOnnection .....etc. QueryPort is very useful and simpler when testing a range of ports